# iPad mini virus? iOS 10.1 what to do?

Tags: iphone, ipad, email, virus, spam

I was browsing the internet when the app store opened by itself, though the back button was greyed out and no apps were showing on that screen. I was unable to click out of it for maybe 1-2 seconds. I wasn't quite sure what was going on until my email app opened by itself too with a composed long message about virus software as a message to send. I didnt get a chance to see the address to whom it was being sent, but have lots of important work contacts I do not want to send weird virus spam to. So I wasnt sure what to do, so i tried quickly closing all apps and shutting off the iPad. I looked through my email accounts on my computer and do not see that any email was actually sent.

So i suspect that my iPad has a virus which is pretty weird given that it is not jailbroken. A cursory search for non-jailbroken iOS viruses mostly brings up chinese viruses, but i cant find much being reported.

Thoughts on what to do from here?

Comment: Even the Chinese "viruses" are normally just spam.  I'm sure your problem lies elsewhere..

Answer (score 2):

You do not have a virus.

Websites and ads can open the App Store and can compose new emails. However it is very bad behaviour of websites or ads to open the  App Store without users consent.

What website did you visit?